# How to do SQL join effectively?

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables.

1. Order
2. Replication.

A single order record can have multiple Replication records. I want to join these two tables, such that i always retrieve a single record out of the join even if multiple records exist.
Sample data

```
Replication table:
ORDID     | STATUS | ID | ERRORMSG | HTTPSTATUS | DELIVERYCNT
=========================================================

1717410307      1   JBM-9e92ae0c  NULL       200   1 
----------
1717410307      1   JBM-9fb59af1  NULL       400   -99
----------
1717410308      1   JBM-0764b091  NULL       403   1
----------
1717410308      1   JBM-0764b091  NULL       200   1
```

---

Order Table:

```
ORDID | ORDTYPE | DATE
----------
1717410307  CAR 22-SEP-2011
1717410308  BUS 23-SEP-2011
```

How can i make a join effectively so as , i will get as many records in order table and a replication table that should be dynamically selected on a priority basis.

The priority can be defined as :

1. Any record with a delivery count of -99
2. HTTPSTATUS != 200

Please guide me how can i proceed with this joining?

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: And what if you have multiple with -99 and HTTP != 200?

Comment: Does a NULL HTTPSTATUS qualify for `HTTPSTATUS != 200`? Normally, a `NULL != 200` yields `NULL` meaning the row will **not** be selected.

Comment: What database engine and version are you using?

Comment: added the [greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use `ORDER BY` clause based on the `HTTPSTATUS` and `DELIVERYCNT`?

In that case you can write a specific `ORDER BY` and getting the `TOP 1` from it (*don't know which RDBMS do you use*) or getting `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ... ) AS RowN WHERE RowN = 1`
But this is the ugly (yet quick) solution.

The other option is to make a subquery where you add a new column which will make the priority calculation.

To make the query effective you should consider indexing (or using RDBMS specific solutions like included columns)